# Как многократно обработать нажатие кнопки с помощью PHP и POST-запроса?

Tags: php, html

В порядке изучения написал следующий код

```
    <form method="POST">
        <input name="buttonAction" type="submit" value="Создать блок!">
    </form>
    
    <?php
    $blockCounter = 0;
    
    if (isset($_POST['buttonAction']))
    {
        $blockCounter++;
        echo "<div> Блок № $blockCounter </div> <br>";
        
    }
    
    ?>
```

В идеале, при каждом нажатии должен появляться блок с порядковым номером n+1, но проблема в том, что блок появляется лишь один, а повторные нажатия эффекта не имеют. Каким образом можно многократно обработать нажатие на кнопку, без использования AJAX и JS?

Comment: у тебя  $blockCounter = 0; То есть всегда 0 и прибавляет +1. Тебе просто нужно передавать дополнительные данные с номером последнего блока

Comment: Почему, в таком случае, не появляется еще один блок с тем же значением после нажатия? Куда, в таком случае, перенести обьявление переменной? Выше формы?

Comment: Кажется, понял, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

У Вас же не api, значит правильным решением будет стартовать сессию
инфа тут: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.session.php

Кука это не правильно потому что я могу сбрасывать ее значение, так как оно храниться в браузере. А значит Ваш счетчик не будет работать правильно. Он просто не будет работать если я буду постоянно сбрасывать куку в 0. В то время сессии хранятся на стороне сервера, и у меня такой возможности не будет.

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос с помощью куки, в которых хранится значение счетчика блоков. Спасибо, Derp